# Is there a CASE statement to apply to several columns to have a like output value changed to another (but different) like value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have several columns that read "Not Specified". I would like them to be blank instead.

Is there a better way to apply a case statement to my ENTIRE query rather than each line, if I'm looking to change the same value in different columns? Currently my query looks like this (plus several columns):

```
       SELECT  
         [user_name]
        ,[employee_number]
        ,CASE [veteran_status] WHEN 'not specified' THEN ''
         ELSE veteran_status
         END AS veteran_status

        ,CASE [ethnic_origin] WHEN 'not specified' THEN ''
       ELSE ethnic_origin 
       END AS ethnic_origin

         ,CASE [gender] WHEN 'not specified' THEN ''
       ELSE gender
       END AS gender

        FROM table.HR
```

I am getting the correct output with the case statements, but looking to see if there's a more efficient way to apply CASE to a mass amount.

Comment: If you're happy with `NULL` (which, makes sense in my opinion as `NULL` means "unknown" and "not specified" also means that the value is not known; aka unknown) you could use `NULLIF`, otherwise no, that's as succinct as you're going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way using which you can apply one principle (logic) to multiple / all columns of a select statement without putting them for each column.

What you can do though is write alternatives that are more concise than **CASE** statement. From your query style, I guess you are using MS SQL server, here is one alternative for MS SQL Server

```
SELECT  
     [user_name]
    ,[employee_number]
    ,iif([veteran_status] = 'not specified', '', [veteran_status]) veteran_status
    ,iif([ethnic_origin] = 'not specified', '', [ethnic_origin]) ethnic_origin
    ,iif([gender] = 'not specified', '', [gender]) gender
FROM table.HR
```

For **Oracle** there is a similar function called **decode**, **Mysql** equivalent is called **if**

That said, **CASE** is standard ANSII SQL, available in all databases. Choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can combine the `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` operators like so:

```
with t1 as (
select user_name
     , employee_number
     , col
     , nullif(value,'not specified') value
  from HR unpivot(value for col in (veteran_status, ethnic_origin, gender)) as x
)
select *
  from t1
  pivot (max(value) for col in (veteran_status, ethnic_origin, gender)) x;
```

If your columns aren't of the same data type, you might need to precondition them by casting them all to the same data type:

```
with t0 as (
select user_name
     , employee_number
     , cast(veteran_status as varchar(30)) veteran_status 
     , cast(ethnic_origin as varchar(30)) ethnic_origin 
     , cast(gender as varchar(30)) gender
  from HR
), t1 as (... from t1 ...)
...
```

However, this may be a *LOT* of work for something easily achievable by more conventional means.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will work when you also want to resolve NULLs with the same value.  You will still need to add this to each column that is referenced, but it uses less code & reduces redundancy overall.

```
ISNULL(NULLIF([veteran_status], ‘not specified’), ‘’) AS [veteran_status]
```

Answer (score -2):

You could join the table to itself, excluding the 'not specified' columns. There isnt a huge gain, however, its an alternative perspective.

```
SELECT  
         user_name
        ,employee_number
        ,veteran_status
        ,ethnic_origin
        ,gender

FROM table.HR hr
        LEFT JOIN table.HR hrvs ON hrvs.employee_number = hr.employee_number  AND hrvs.veteran_status <> 'not specified'
        LEFT JOIN table.HR hreo ON hreo.employee_number = hr.employee_number  AND hreo.ethnic_origin <> 'not specified'
        LEFT JOIN table.HR hrge ON hrge.employee_number = hr.employee_number  AND hrge.gender <> 'not specified'
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It would not produce the same results, as the poster's attempt would not eliminate the rows like yours, but would simply display an empty string instead of *not specified* for one or more columns. There's a difference between displaying a different value for the column and eliminating the row entirely.

Comment: This query will not yield the desired result